# Where to download latest JDK EE instead of glassfish

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-8

When i downloaded jdk ee few years ago, got "jdk-8u231-windows-x64.exe" file and installed it. It created "jdk1.8.0_231" folder and i have used it for JAVA_HOME.

But when i tried to download latest JDK EE now, i got "glassfish" folder in it.

What is this change ? Why is this change for ?

Note: I know Oracle gave Java EE to Eclipse and it is now called as Jakarta EE. But even in eclipse site or oracle site, i could only find glassfish downloads, not jdk ee.

Please help me to understand this.

Thanks

Comment: You are really confused.  `jdk-8u231-windows-x64.exe` is not a Java EE installer.  It is a Java SE JDK installer.  And there is no such thing as "JDK EE".

Comment: What you actually need to do is install: Glassfish from https://glassfish.org/download AND a Java JDK (or JRE) from your preferred Java vendor.

Comment: Note the documentation says that Glassfish will run on Java 8 patch 144 or later ... but a newer (Java 11 or Java 17) JDK would be a better idea.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a *JDK EE*.

## JDK

A [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) is an implementation of the [Java™ SE (Standard Edition) specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). A JDK is composed of development tools such as a compiler, and of runtime tools that include a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) and an implementation of the standard libraries including the classes such as `ArrayList`, `LocalDate`, and so on.

The first sentence of the linked Wikipedia article on JDK is incorrect in claiming Oracle is the sole vendor. Oracle Corporation is but one of several vendors providing builds and installers for a JDK. Other vendors include, off the top of my head: Amazon, Azul Systems, Microsoft, Adoptium, SAP, BellSoft, Red Hat/IBM, Pivotal, and maybe more. Nowadays, most of these companies’ offerings are based largely or entirely on the open-source code base collaboratively built at the *OpenJDK* project. So you will find the quality and performance to be largely the same across these JDK products.

So your first chore is to choose a vendor and obtain and install a JDK. Some JDK products are free-of-cost and some require a fee. Be aware at the time of download. See [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-3-0-0-ocrt-2021-bca75c88d23b) for more information.

Choose a version of JDK appropriate to your choice of Jakarta EE product discussed below. Be aware that Java 8, 11, and 17 are the long-term support (LTS) versions of Java.

## Jakarta EE

Jakarta EE, formerly known as Java EE (Enterprise Edition), is a collection of dozens of specifications for various kinds of enterprise-oriented software you may want to run on top of your Java SE JDK installation.

Most of these products are aimed at server-side usage. A few can also be used in desktop apps, such as [*Jakarta Bean Validation*](http://Q%20https://beanvalidation.org/) and [*Jakarta Contexts and Dependency Injection*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/).

The Jakarta EE specifications are owned by the Eclipse Foundation, having been donated by Oracle Corp. Their further development is proceeding in a transparent open-source manner.

Several vendors provide implementations of the various Jakarta EE specifications. Some are available individually as a library to include in your app. And some vendors offer an assortment of products bundled together to be run as an application server.

The [*Glassfish*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish) product you mentioned in your Question is one such application server offering. Similar products from various vendors include *Payara*, *Open Liberty*, *Wildfly*, *JBoss*, and more.

Your second chore is to choose a vendor and obtain a Jakarta EE compliant application server product. You then install that on the same machine you installed the JDK.

If you are starting fresh on a new project, I would suggest using [Java 17](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17) with an app server compliant with [Jakarta EE 9.1](https://jakarta.ee/release/9.1/). [*Eclipse GlassFish*](https://glassfish.org/) 6.2.3 is one such product to consider. The Jakarta EE site maintains a [list of compliant products](https://jakarta.ee/compatibility/).